# Realizing the design from a design professional in code

Tags: gwt, designer

I typically work on web apps that will only be used by a small group of well-controlled people, but now find that I'm writing something that has the potential to be used by a very large population. This means that the design and "look" will be very important to the success.

While I can certainly code up something functional, it ain't gonna look pretty, so I know that I'll need to get an outside designer to make things look good. Never having worked that way before I had a few questions about the mechanics of how this happens and how to try to make things easier.

We do Java, so when building a rich interface, we use GWT. I know that when working with designers, they typically provide images of what the interface should look like without any type of "useable" output. My question is how best to bridge that gap between a simple drawing of an interface to a fully functional realized one.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "it depends", as always.

Nowadays, I don't think you can work wit someone who simply provides PhotoShop mockups. At least not at your level. Mockups are simply too static, and translating those mockups to actual pages that actually work with different browsers properly is a skill set all its own.

So, you need someone beyond simply a designer, especially if you are planning any javascript wizardry, animations, or other dynamic elements that don't capture at all well on a static image.

What you really want is an "operational" mockup. Static HTML files that look and behave as best as can be done to what the UI designer wants to do, including transitions, work flow, etc. This artifact can be run through all of the stake holders as a live mockup, letting folks "Feel" the site.

Once you have these HTML files, you can then do your part of backfilling these pages with actual server side content. Obviously you can start early working on models and working with the designers so as to have services ready to support the site functionality, but you shouldn't be committing any real time in to actual pages for the site.

As for interacting with the designers, I talk more about that over here: [How can I make my JSP project easier for a designer to work with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6599884/how-can-i-make-my-jsp-project-easier-for-a-designer-to-work-with/6604384#6604384)

Comment: Ha, I was going to link to my question too.  Will's answer over there is a good one.  Getting fully functional html (including javascript) and then just replacing the dynamic portions with your java is the fastest and easiest way to incorporate work from your designer.  Not have done much gwt, I'm not sure how well that maps.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on a project very much like this. We had "comps" which were pictures of what the interface would look like. We identified common objects and build modules. Then built pages (this was for a web app) from modules plus any elements that were unique to that "comp".

A couple things to keep in mind that will make life much easier: use the comps/drawings as more of a recommendation rather than set in stone design. Try to identify common pieces early on and reuse code.

Also, designers aren't user experience gods. They often have a good idea of how things should work, but if you are close to your product and have a lot of product knowledge, don't be afraid to tweak the design as you and your group see fit. One thing that designers typically lack is product knowledge. They know a lot about general user experience and how a site should work, but they often won't know the in's and out's of your use cases and products.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with GWT, you should look for designers who are expert in CSS. Apart from, may be, the main layout of the website, all the application components like form fields, dialogs, tabs and grids etc. will need to be styled using CSS.

If the designers are not experienced in working with GWT, share the [GWT's documentation](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html) about styling with them. It's a good idea to read these yourself as well. Specifically explore the GWT's [theme-ing](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCss.html#themes) system.

Also try to make use of [UiBinder](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) as much as possible. This would allow you to stay as close to traditional HTML based design while still enjoying the GWT high level object oriented interfaces (both [widgets](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_Widget_World) and [DOM](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html#Hello_World)).

Optionally you might want to tell the designers that GWT [image bundles](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiImageBundles.html) will automatically do "CSS Sprites" so they don't need to worry about page load performance issues related to images.